# Expectation of a conditional expectation with more than one variable in conditional part

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have three indicator variables:
$I_1 =1$ or $0$ with some probability
$I_2 =1$ or $0$ with some probability
$J=1$ or $0$ and the value of $J$ depends on $I_1, I_2$. $I_1, I_2$ are independent.

We also have a function $NP$ which is $NP(I_1,I_2,J)$ i.e. it is function of the three indicator variables. So we can get $E[NP|I_1=1,I_2=1,J=1], \ldots$ There will be total 8 such conditional expectations.

Can we write $E[NP]=(E[NP|I_1=1,I_2=1,J=1])*P(I_1=1,I_2=1,J=1) + \cdots$ i.e. sum of all the 8 conditionals multiplied by the corresponding joint probability ?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(A_i)_i$ denote a partition of the probability space and $X$ some integrable random variable, then Bayes' formula reads
$$
E(X)=\sum_iE(X\mid A_i)P(A_i).
$$
Use this with $X=NP$, and $(A_i)_i$ the partition generated by $(I_1,I_2,J)$.

Beware though that one needs every $P(A_i)$ to be positive for the formula to make sense, here this means that $P(I_1=u,I_2=v,J=w)\gt0$ for every $u$, $v$ and $w$ in $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had a follow up question. What happens if some of the $P(I_1 = u, I_2 = v, J = w)$ are zero ? In that case how do we write $E[NP]$ ?

Comment: As the same sum as above except that one omits every $i$ such that $P(A_i)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any theoretical justification for omitting every $i$ such that $P(A_i)=0$ and still writing $E[NP]$ ? Isn't that an approximation ?

Comment: No approximation here since $E(X;A)=0$ for every $A$ such that $P(A)=0$.